# Interpreting odd's ratios

Tags: odds-ratio

If A is a binary faction (1 A and 0 not A) and if the odds ratios of A to B is (say) 1.2409 (24 percent or e ^ 0.2158). Then is the odds ratio of B to A 76% or 1 – 0.24?

Comment: the odds ratio of B to A = 1/1.0249.

Comment: I constantly  mix odds and odds ratio up. I ended up creating a confusion table like the one below.

Comment: Definition of OR of A to B: $OR_{AB} = \frac {P(A=1)/(1-P(A=1))} {P(B=1)/(1-P(B=1))}$. Definition of OR of B to A: $OR_{BA} = \frac {P(B=1)/(1-P(B=1))}{P(A=1)/(1-P(A=1))}$. So $OR_{BA} = 1/OR_{AB}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither, maybe you are confused with odds and odds-ratios. But **odds** and **odd ratios** are two different things.

The odds ratio is defined as the ratio of the odds of A in the presence of B and the odds of A in the absence of B. Or equivalently (due to symmetry), the ratio of the odds of B in the presence of A and the odds of B in the absence of A.

Given your example, you could construct the following 2x2 table:

[image]

Therefore, if the odds ratio of A to B is 1.2409 to 1, then the odds ratio of B to A is 1.2409 to 1 too.

Comment: Finding that (10/12)>1 should tell you something needs changing.